# Why can PHP calculate 0.1 + 0.2 when other languages fail?

Tags: php, floating-point

As described in [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken), `0.1 + 0.2` evaluates to `0.30000000000000004` in most programming languages.

However, PHP, presumably due to being the best of all the programming languages, is able to calculate 0.1 + 0.2 correctly:

```
php > echo 0.1 + 0.2;
0.3
php > var_dump(0.1 + 0.2);
float(0.3)
```

However, despite the output shown above, 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3:

```
php > var_dump(0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3);
bool(false)
```

What's going on here?

Comment: You made me lol at "PHP being the best of all". It is one of the most magical, though, which may be why it hides the precision error from you, while it obviously is still there.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

PHP has a [`precision`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.precision) configuration value which sets the number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers. It is 14 by default, which is the reason `0.1 + 0.2` is displayed as `0.3`.

If, however, you do this:

```
ini_set('precision', 17);
echo 0.1 + 0.2;
```

you get `0.30000000000000004`